# Setting WPF text backcolor with focus and image

Tags: wpf, validation, focus, backcolor

WPF /MVVM Pattern

User control with multiple textboxes using validation attributes.
In the following style, everything works as intended- EXCEPT for those with a validation error, the Focused backcolor is not being set, due to the method used in the control template to set the error image.

If I remove the control template, the backcolor is set properly when focused if the validation error is set. With the template, backcolor is always white/default.

Any suggestions on the XAML required to have both - different backcolor when focused and the error image when validation fails?

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="1" />
    <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding Description}"/>

    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightYellow"/>
        </Trigger>

        <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="ToolTip"
                    Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=(Validation.Errors).CurrentItem.ErrorContent}"/>

            <!--adds the error image and border, but also prevents background color change OnFocus-->
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Border  
                                    BorderBrush="#d99" x:Name="textBorder" CornerRadius="4" 
                                    BorderThickness="2" >
                                <ScrollViewer Margin="0" x:Name="PART_ContentHost"/>
                            </Border>
                            <Image Name="ErrorImage" Width="24" Height="24" Margin="0,0,4,0"
                                    Source="/Images/error.png" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                            </Image>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check out [the DependencyProperty precedence rules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230.aspx)

What happens here is that the `ControlTemplate` you define overrides the `Style.Triggers` defined just before.

What you can do to make it work is to set the actual `Style` with appropriate `Triggers` directly inside of the `ControlTemplate`
Otherwise, as you've seen, WPF will just use the default template for a `Grid`.

The code should look like that:

```
<Style.Triggers>

    <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
        <Setter Property="ToolTip"
                Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=(Validation.Errors).CurrentItem.ErrorContent}"/>

        <!--adds the error image and border, but also prevents background color change OnFocus-->
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                    <Grid>
                    <Grid.Style>
                      <Style TargetType="{x:Type Grid}">
                        <Style.Triggers>
    <!-- The trigger about IsFocused should be here!
    <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightYellow"/>
    </Trigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                      </Style>
                    </Grid.Style>
                        <Border  
                                BorderBrush="#d99" x:Name="textBorder" CornerRadius="4" 
                                BorderThickness="2" >
                            <ScrollViewer Margin="0" x:Name="PART_ContentHost"/>
                        </Border>
                        <Image Name="ErrorImage" Width="24" Height="24" Margin="0,0,4,0"
                                Source="/Images/error.png" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                        </Image>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Trigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```